# Преобразовать строку Pandas в словарь

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, словари

Добрый день.

У меня есть датафрейм пандаса с составным индексом. Мне нужно перебрать все строки и каждую превратить в словарь вида `{название_колонки: значение}`.

Причем, чтобы туда попадали и индексные колонки, и простые.

Всё утро читаю документацию, написал вот такое:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
  idx_dct = dict(zip(df.index.names, row[0]))
  val_dct = dict(zip(df.columns, row[1:]))
  res_dct = dict(idx_dct, **val_dct)
  print(res_dct)
```

Результат, конечно, получен. Но код мне совершенно не нравится и есть такое ощущение, что я изобретаю велосипед.

Может быть, в пандасе есть какие-то специальные методы для того, что я хочу?

UPD: Исходные датафрейм получен как pivot_table от другого датафрейма и имеет вид:

```
           val
idx1 idx2     
1    1       1
     2       8
3    3       2
```

Я хочу получить список словарей:

```
{'idx2': 1, 'idx1': 1, 'val': 1}
{'idx2': 2, 'idx1': 1, 'val': 8}
{'idx2': 3, 'idx1': 3, 'val': 2}
```

(На самом деле, индексных и обычных колонок будет в несколько раз больше и заранее их перечня нет, его нужно выцеплять из самого датафрейма)

Comment: Вы можете привести пример вашего DataFrame'а (3-5 строк) и словарь, который вы хотите получить из указанного DF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** с использованием DF приведенном в измененном вопросе:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
           val
idx1 idx2
1    1       1
     2       8
3    3       2

In [25]: df.reset_index().to_dict('records')
Out[25]:
[{'idx1': 1, 'idx2': 1, 'val': 1},
 {'idx1': 1, 'idx2': 2, 'val': 8},
 {'idx1': 3, 'idx2': 3, 'val': 2}]
```

---

Это делается очень просто (если я правильно понял вопрос):

Пример DF:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
                     a         b         c         d
first second
bar   one     1.009758 -0.384033  1.668898 -1.302448
      two    -0.356388  0.341411  0.109125 -0.202563
baz   one     0.495853  1.052266 -0.264984 -0.343306
      two    -1.571577 -0.646954 -0.187620  0.594999
foo   one    -1.228468  0.092976  0.030144 -2.099977
      two     1.588960  1.000785  0.875712  2.584941
qux   one     0.590220 -1.305587  1.270706 -0.351706
      two    -0.643912 -0.597870 -0.921415  1.034810
```

Решение - получаем список словарей:

```
In [16]: df.reset_index().to_dict('records')
Out[16]:
[{'a': 1.0097583468728302,
  'b': -0.3840332867221293,
  'c': 1.6688984434963192,
  'd': -1.3024483316392064,
  'first': 'bar',
  'second': 'one'},
 {'a': -0.3563883540306324,
  'b': 0.3414110282364142,
  'c': 0.10912532819005455,
  'd': -0.20256250429340558,
  'first': 'bar',
  'second': 'two'},
 {'a': 0.4958529642501866,
  'b': 1.0522662314224476,
  'c': -0.26498405219799387,
  'd': -0.3433064145597633,
  'first': 'baz',
  'second': 'one'},
 {'a': -1.5715767690652416,
  'b': -0.6469535251089127,
  'c': -0.18762036338991817,
  'd': 0.5949991666517178,
  'first': 'baz',
  'second': 'two'},
 {'a': -1.2284678785281338,
  'b': 0.09297646032741932,
  'c': 0.030143674588866923,
  'd': -2.0999765379840656,
  'first': 'foo',
  'second': 'one'},
 {'a': 1.5889599693307292,
  'b': 1.0007848283996947,
  'c': 0.8757119900619003,
  'd': 2.5849411147424046,
  'first': 'foo',
  'second': 'two'},
 {'a': 0.5902198338135144,
  'b': -1.305587223739773,
  'c': 1.270706125958048,
  'd': -0.3517064424514258,
  'first': 'qux',
  'second': 'one'},
 {'a': -0.6439118906436252,
  'b': -0.5978697429631142,
  'c': -0.9214146623018005,
  'd': 1.034810389524401,
  'first': 'qux',
  'second': 'two'}]
```

Comment: Да, это именно то, что я искал ) Спасибо.

Comment: @Александр, пожалуйста :)